# When a player is killed in Bang! can they still talk?

Tags: bang

When a player is eliminated, can they still talk and discuss strategy on the table or do they have to stay silent?

Answer (score 19):

The rules don't explicitly cover this, so we must use our own judgement.

When a player dies, they reveal their role and their cards. The dead player has no more hidden information. Therefore, I see no reason why they should be required to remain silent. Additionally, one could argue that they aren't even playing the game any longer, and therefore can't possibly be bound by its rules. (In before someone comments that some Bang! character I don't know about can revive.)

If your play group really has an issue with dead players influencing opinions after death, then introduce a house rule. Dead players can't speak (at least about the game).

Comment: Well there are cards in expansions that bring players back into the game and the length they stay in the game varies based on the mechanic that brings them back. But back to the bigger issue is depending on your situation depending on where you are gaming if someone gets killed early on then they might have to sit around doing nothing for a good while because games can last for a while before a second player dies. As for influencing games will a dead player have any more information then when they where alive? Unless they gain hidden information after their death it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @JoeW *"Will a dead player have any more information then when they where alive?"* No, they will have **less** hidden information than when they were alive, because they have revealed their role as well as their cards. I stated this in the answer.

Comment: Sorry was a bit unclear but was just adding more thought to your answer and was trying to point out that a player doesn't gain any information when they are eliminated.

Answer (score 3):

### Is there rule for table talk?

There is nothing in the [rules](http://www.dvgiochi.net/bang/bang_rules.pdf) which would allow/disallow the talking of dead players. The official [FAQ](http://www.dvgiochi.net/bang/bang_faq_eng.pdf) says

> Q1. Can players talk during the game?
>
> A. Of course! That's one of the most amusing aspects of the game. --

but even there nothing is said explicitly about dead players.  This means that the decision must be made between the players (a house rule).

### But does it matter?

**Normally**: No. It should not matter if the dead players can talk. (Except if you let them see other players' playing/role cards)

**When playing with the tournament points system** ([BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/29284/bang-official-tournament-scoring), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang!#Official_tournament_score), [Bang.cz](http://www.bang.cz/en/rules-and-faq/special-rules/64-official-tournament-scoring-system.html)): Yes, it matters. Also the dead players may get points, and therefore it is fair to give the players opportunity to affect the outcome (and their score) by talking. This game is very much a social game, where bluffing and manipulation has a huge role.